# Inheritance error: expected class-name before '{' token

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I have tried every combination of `#include` statements that I can think of, and nothing is working. I am trying to write a basic inheritance program but i keep getting the error `error: expected class-name before '}' token` and I just do not know what to do about it anymore. I've tried having my `main()` include the `.cpp` file of the Executive class, however this error shows up. The program includes 5 types of employees all inherited from the `Employee` class, and I'm assuming that they are all the same error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "Employee.cpp"
#include "Manager.cpp"
#include "Executive.cpp"
#include "Technical.cpp"
#include "Software.cpp"
#include "Test.cpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Employee emp[3];

    Executive emp0("John", "Doe", "VP", 100000.0, 1000000.0, 2000.0);
    Software emp1("Vincent", "Giuliana", "Project Leader", 150000.0, 200000.0, 1000.0);
    Test emp2("Lauren", "Wallis", "Overseer of Testing", 95000, 115000);

    emp[0] = emp0;
    emp[1] = emp1;
    emp[2] = emp2;

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
        emp[i].displayInformation();

    emp0.displayInformation();
    emp1.displayInformation();
    emp2.displayInformation();

    return 0;
}
```

My `Employee.h` header file is as follows:

```
#ifndef EMPLOYEE_H_INCLUDED
#define EMPLOYEE_H_INCLUDED

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Employee
{
private:
    string fName, lName, jobTitle;
    double baseSalary, salary;

public:
    Employee();
    Employee(string fName, string lName, string jobTitle, double baseSalary);
    void calculateSalary(double baseSalary);
    void displayName();
    void displayBSalary();
    void displayJobTitle();
    void displayInformation();

...
getters
...

...
setters
...
};

#endif // EMPLOYEE_H_INCLUDED
```

My `Employee.cpp` is:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include "Employee.h"

using namespace std;

Employee::Employee()
{
    fName = "";
    lName = "";
    jobTitle = "";
    baseSalary = 000000;
}

...

void Employee::setBSalary(double bs) //sets base salary as parameter
{
    baseSalary = bs;
}
```

The top of the `Executive.h` header class:

```
#ifndef EXECUTIVE_H_INCLUDED
#define EXECUTIVE_H_INCLUDED

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

//#include "Employee.h"

using namespace std;

class Executive : public Employee
{
private:
    string fName, lName, jobTitle;
    double baseSalary, salary, bonus, stockOption;

public:
...
};

#endif // Executive_H_INCLUDED
```

And last but not least, the `Executive.cpp` file...
    #include 
    #include

```
#include "Executive.h"

using namespace std;

Executive::Executive()
{
    fName = fN;
    lName = lN;
    jobTitle = jt;
    baseSalary = bs;
    bonus = b;
    stockOption = so;
}

...

void Executive::setSO(double so) //sets stock option as parameter
{
    stockOption = so;
}
```

I think that I have tried to include each header in each file and still, nothing. Any help would be appreciated, and I thank anyone very much in advance!

Comment: You should tag questions with the language you are using. More people will see your question then.

Comment: For what file and what line do you get the error?

Comment: Executive.h line 12
class Executive : public Employee
{

Comment: Why are you including `.cpp` files into your main program? That's not the way things are usually done.

Comment: How do you build this? Do you compile each `.cpp` file separately (using GCC, you'd do this with `-o Executive.o -c Executive.cpp`), and finally link them together? In that case, do you get the error when you compile `Executive.cpp`, or when you compile one of the other files?

Comment: i was just trying that combination -- I found out that it doesn't work, but that was my last attempt so I just left it hoping I could get help here...

@jogojapan I am using Code::Blocks to write, compile and run. I'm assuming that I will have the same errors on the other four files, too, as they are the same format, but I am not positive. My assumption is that the compilation stops once it reaches this error.

Comment: The cause of this may be a missing closing brace or something like that somewhere in the code included before the `Executive` class definition. If, for example, you try compiling `Employee.cpp` (which includes `Employee.h` and nothing else), and a similar error occurs, we could at least rule out that the cause of the problem is in `Executive.h`.

Answer (score 4):

You must

```
#include "Employee.h"
```

in `Executive.h`, because the compiler must see the declaration of `Employee`, when a class inherits from it. So, just remove the comments from the `#include`

Comment: Thank you -- that got rid of that error, but then a bunch of redefinition errors showed up in their place.